# model.predict.datasync() takes time to give results which causes lag in camera. How to get results / predictions instantly?

Tags: react-native, tensorflow.js, teachable-machine

I'm using Tensorflow js in react native and I'm getting the correct predictions for my model but it takes a lot of time to give results. For eg I'm using a custom model created by me in teachable machine by Google. But the .datasync() takes time approx. 1 second whole to give results. This causes a physical lag in the camera I want to get results instantly. This is my code below: -

```js
<TensorCamera
          style={styles.camera}
          flashMode={Camera.Constants.FlashMode.off}
          type={Camera.Constants.Type.back}
          resizeWidth={224}
          resizeHeight={224}
          resizeDepth={3}
          onReady={handleCameraStream}
          autorender={true}
        />
//
const handleCameraStream = (imageAsTensors) => {
    try {
    } catch (e) {
      // console.log("Tensor 1 not found!");
    }
    const loop = async () => {
      // && detected == true
      if (model !== null) {
        if (frameCount % makePredictionsEveryNFrames === 0) {
          const imageTensor = imageAsTensors.next().value;
          await getPrediction(imageTensor);
          // .catch(e => console.log(e));
        }
      }

      frameCount += 1;
      frameCount = frameCount % makePredictionsEveryNFrames;
      requestAnimationFrameId = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    };
    loop();

    //loop infinitely to constantly make predictions
  };
//
const getPrediction = async (tensor) => {
    // if (!videoLink) {
    if (!tensor) {
      console.log("Tensor not found!");
      return;
    }
    //
    const imageData2 = tensor.resizeBilinear([224, 224]);
    // tf.image.resizeBilinear(tensor, [224, 224]);
    const normalized = imageData2.cast("float32").div(127.5).sub(1);
    const final = tf.expandDims(normalized, 0);
    //
    console.time();
    const prediction = model.predict(final).dataSync();
   
    console.timeEnd();
    console.log("Predictions:", prediction);
}
```

I heard about using .data() instead of .datasync() but I don't know how to implement .data() in my current code. please help.

Answer (score 0):

`predict` is what takes time - and that is really up to your model
maybe it can run faster on different backend (no idea which backend you're using, default for browsers would be `webgl`), but in reality it is what it is without rearchitecting the model items.

`datasync` simply downloads results from wherever tensors are (e.g. in gpu vram) to your variable in js.

yes, you could use `data` instead which is an async call, but difference is couple of ms at best - its not going to speed up model execution at all.

btw, you're not releasing tensors anywhere - your application has some serious memory leaks.

Comment: my model is not even big tho . im currently using webgl as backend as others were slower in comparison . can you tell me where to release tensors like you mentioned ?  can you edit my code above and tell me where to release tensors ? also im using this in my react native app not a browser . how to rearchitect the model items as you mentioned above ? I made a model with 4 classes to detect with googles teachable machine platform I can share my model.json file with you if you want and my model.weights.bin file is around 2.2mb . pls help bro its urgent .

Comment: regarding tensor deallocation, i've provided examples in different posts - editing your code is not what i'd do here. regarding model reachitecture, that is a massive topic - and makes no sense to talk about it if your model is a simple model that you haven't even designed, you just created it using teachable machine. and no wonder its slow as teachable machine produces anything but efficient models.

Comment: can you please tell me what else can I do in order to fix this issue ? how to model that is fast/efficient ?

Comment: how to create an efficient model is a science, not something than be done in a quick post or comment. start with some easy examples <https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tfjs-training-classfication/index.html#0>